# How to get collection of pagination in template?

Tags: collection, magento2.1.5, pagination

**These are my block methods:**

```
    public function getProductsViewHistory() {
        $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
        $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 1;
        $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-6 month"));
        $product = $this->customerProductViewHistory->create();
        $product->addFieldToFilter('subject_id',array('eq'=> $this->getLoggedInUserId() ))
        ->addFieldToFilter('logged_at',array('from'=> $fromDate ))
        ->addFieldToSelect('object_id')
        ->getSelect()->group('object_id');
        $product->setPageSize( self::PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE );
        $product->setCurPage($page);
        return $product;
    }     
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        // $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('News'));
        if ($this->getProductsViewHistory()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
                'history.pager'
            )->setAvailableLimit(array( self::PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE=>self::PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE))
->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection( $this->getProductsViewHistory() );
                $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
                $this->getProductsViewHistory()->load();
            }
            return $this;
        }
   public function getPagerHtml()
     {
         return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
     }
```

**And this is my template file.**

```
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
    <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php
$collection = $this->getCollection();  
 foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value->getData());
 }
?>
```

**I get this error:**

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

If I comment out the part to show collection, I'm successfully getting pagination as intended.
What am I missing?

Comment: have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: Exactly not. abdul gave me a solution which I was not looking for. Still looking for the best.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use below syntax,

```
<?php
$items = $block->getCollection();  
 foreach ($items as $value) {
    var_dump($value->getData());
 }
?>
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have still issue.

Comment: No mate , the issue persists.

Comment: @Purushotam Actually what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to get the collection set by pagination even if the collection is ordered randomly,  I'm confused about the purpose of  $this->getProductsViewHistory()->load();     and return $this;

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php $products = $block->getProductsViewHistory(); ?>
<?php if ($products && count($products)): ?>
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
    <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
    <?php print_r($product->getData());?>  
<?php endforeach; ?> 

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I knew this technique. It is a way. But what if the collection I'm fetching is randomly ordered, the result will be different for the case of calling while in _prepareLayout(), and the call from template file. I need the same collection in both function call.

Comment: are you need product collection in randomly right?

Comment: But above code working fine?

Comment: Yes in another task I need this feature on random collection.

Comment: Ok. let me check and reply

Comment: And another point is , if I have to  call my own method to get the collection then what is the purpose of                   $this->getProductsViewHistory()->load();
            and
            return $this; in _prepareLayout();

Comment: see here for more details http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/